# How to detect if SKAction is running

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, detect, skaction

This is my SKAction:

```
 naarRechts  = SKAction.moveToX(positionX , duration: 0.22)
player.runAction(naarRechts)
```

In that duration of 0.22 sec I do NOT want this action to run:

```
    if CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame, car.frame){
        player.position.x = car.position.x
    }
```

What is the magic line of code where I can detect if my first SKAction is running, or to detect wether the player is in movement or not..

Comment: hasActions and actionForKey:, see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/hasActions and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/actionForKey:

Comment: I think I need the hasActions, but how do I use it, can you give me an example? thank you!

Comment: like LearnCocos2D said use `player.runAction(naarRechts,withKey:"naarRechts")` and then check for the action with `if player.actionForKey("naarRechts") != nil { /* do something here */ }`

Comment: this was the magic line I was looking for. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class variable `var playerIsInAction = false` then set it to `true` just after you run the action. Also change the method so that you can write a completion code (after the action ends) where you set the bool back to `false`.

It should be something like this :

```
playerIsInAction = true
player.runAction(naarRechts, completion: {() in 
    playerIsInAction = false
})
```

And you check for the bool

```
if CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame, car.frame) && playerIsInAction == false {
    //Code
}
```

Comment: This will not work in my situation because of the duration(0.22) of my SKaction. but thank you